Asking help with booting centos7.9 issue
I want to install a centos7.9 minimal version, and burn the iso image into a use device,
the startup guide to install centos7, and i press enter, then failed.
After searching many answers from internet, inst.stage2=hd:/dev/sda1 would be the answer.
after try, there is also a error happen like this:


Is there a reason for CentOS 7? That is effectively very old, and simply might be missing drivers necessary to work on your machine.

"and burn the iso image into a use device" - you've not done that correctly.

A CentOS variant besides AlmaLinux is also RockyLinux: Aboout.  I believe this is the "unofficial" continuation of CentOS

i use rufus to handle the centos7.9 into usb device, the centos7.9 is from https://img.cs.montana.edu/linux/centos/7/isos/x86_64/CentOS-7-x86_64-Minimal-2009.iso

possibly, there might be some chances for missing drivers about centos7.9 with the new  nvme 2.0 ssd hardware, now i go to the shopping squares to check this issue ~

ok, i would try the almalinux, thanks

As pointed out above - CentOS is basically dead. The best option today is to try something more modern, such as AlmaLinux 9.x.
But, assuming you have a good reason for using CentOS7, there are a few gotchas when creating the disk. As this page (from 2019) points out:

Applications known (2019) that do NOT work are: unetbootin, multibootusb and universal usb installler - do NOT use these. Also Rufus does not work correctly if the wrong options are chosen so the tool is best avoided.


ok, i will give it a try for almalinux 9.x ! I'm just a little familar with centos7.9, can now i need to go outside to check the new ssd whether it is fine or not, which i think may be it is fresh new, no partion operation so that the computer does not recognize ~
